# Is it okay to use old letters of recommendation?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I have letters of recommendations from my professors and employers which I had asked for last year while applying to colleges. Due to some circumstances, I decided not to go and apply to colleges again this year. Is it okay if I use the letters of recommendation which they had written earlier? I think asking for them to write another recommendation will be getting on their nerves, since they are busy. Also, my old recommendation letters of last year has the dates of recommendation on them. Will this be a problem if I apply with those dates?

Comment: Where? I think they are fine if they are only a year old, especially where recommendation letters are just a formality but some countries give them more weight in the recruitment process. In the EU, I have reused 18 months old recommendation letters without problem.

Comment: Where are you located in the world? Were these letter of recommendation sent to you rather than to where you were applying?

Comment: I don't see much problems as for there shouldn't be a reason for the writers to have changed idea about you and because the letters serve the same purpose.